# How to configure vscode in order to discover python unittests

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, automated-tests

I want to create automation tests for web application with Visual Studio code, Python and unittest. However my Test Explorer fails to discover tests (no error appears it is just empty).

Despite that i have needed extensions (Python, Test Explorer UI and Python Test Explorer), prepared settings.json and required methods' and classes' decoration, commands like run all tests or discover doesn't work out. 
However debugging whole file actually runs tests (i see output in terminal).

CODE:

```
import unittest

class testClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_method(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)
    def test_method2(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

SETTINGS:

```
{
    "testExplorer.showOnRun": true,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.pyTestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\Cezary\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python.exe"
}
```

Comment: What versions of Visual Studio, Python, and Unittest are you using? Also, please explicitly state your question so that no one has to guess.

Comment: I am using visual studio code 1.35.1 and Python 3.7.3. Unitest package i am just importing via import keyword, i didnt make any changes over here.

Comment: Have you checked the "Test discovery section"?
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/unit-testing#_test-discovery

Try to name your file "test_yourtest.py"

Comment: I tried it but sadly it didnt work. I have also a __init__.py file added to same folder as test file but still no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of things to consider:

1. You should name your test files starting with `test_`.
2. Run `python -m unittest discover` in your project root directory. If that does not find your tests, VSCode won't find them either.
3. Place a test file at the root folder to see if it can be found / afterwards move it to submodules (consider `__init__.py` files)

Comment: It worked! :D for all this time the problem was that i was opening .py test file as a file in editor instead of whole folder. Thank you very much!